# Como tornar a propriedade isTrusted do PointerEvent verdadeira?

Tags: javascript, eventos-do-mouse

#### Estou personificando algumas ações de cliques em uma página a partir de determinadas condições!

No entanto, a página não **aceita** o evento clique quando NÃO É disparado por uma ação do usuário, por exemplo..

```js
document.querySelector("elemento_x").click();
```

Quando imprimo o eventTarget no `console.log()` ele me retorna o seguinte:

> *PointerEvent {**isTrusted: false**, pointerId: -1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}*

Percebo que quando é disparado por uma ação minha, a propriedade **isTrusted** retorna **true**.

> *PointerEvent {**isTrusted: true**, pointerId: 1, width: 1, height: 1, pressure: 0, …}*

###### É possível definir o evento `click()` como confiável? Existe uma forma de burlar isto? Na documentação [Event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) da MDN diz que é uma propriedade exclusiva para leitura, o que me faz perder as esperanças..

<sup>Observação! estou aberto a sugestões e métodos.</sup>

Comment: Dá para enganar o navegador Chrome enviando um evento de mouse pelo DevTools em modo de depuração https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Input/#method-dispatchMouseEvent , quanto aos outros navegadores não sei.

Comment: Só um adendo mesmo sendo gerados por software os eventos click são disparados, veja o exemplo: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/Untrusted#index.html

Comment: Maravilha!! vou olhar.. @AugustoVasques por sinal, da pra enganar tbm com o modo de debugger das extensões, no chrome??

Comment: Eu não sei como está no momento, mas há algum tempo sim era possível, mas vai ter que consultar a documentação pois houveram muitas mudanças na API de extensões.

Comment: massa! vou analisar e ver no que resulta.. valeu a contribuição!

Comment: Acho que é esse endpoint na API de Extensões do Chrome que esta falando https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/#method-sendCommand

Comment: Olha, não conheço muito como funciona esse `isTrusted` internamente. Mas, se a ideia é garantir que o clique veio de um usuário e isso for burlavel, o método não serve para nada - e provavelmente será atualizado para uma versão não burlavel assim que a falha for identificada... Eu diria que, se tua intenção é criar testes e, nesses testes, o `isTrusted`  precisa retornar `true`, a melhor forma é usar um mock para isso (talvez usando sinon.js?).

Comment: @LeonardoAlvesMachado, concordo e você tem toda a razão. Mas os métodos discutidos aqui são alternativas externas ao contexto do código fonte, São os mesmos mecanismos que o Selenium, Puppeteer e Playwright usam para automatizar os navegadores.

Comment: @AugustoVasques penso que se for para debater Selenium ou Puppet então não é a questão de burlar o isTrusted, a pergunta dá a entender que deseja mudar no nivel runtime rodando via camada JavaScript do navegador. Se não for isso então é sugestão de software, que torna a pergunta off-topic. Se for o caso do primeiro, via JS do browser, então é impossível e não faz sentido, porque isso é um recurso para evitar "trapaças".